# Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String[])'

Tags: java, android

Anyone please tell me where and how should i correct this

public class Book_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView tvtitle,tvdescription,tvcategory;
private ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    tvtitle =  findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
   TextView tvdescription = findViewById(R.id.txtdes);
    tvcategory = findViewById(R.id.txtcat);
    img = findViewById(R.id.bookthumbnail);

    // Recieve data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
    String Category = intent.getExtras().getString("Category");
    String[] Description = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("Description");
    int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Thumbnail") ;

    // Setting values

    tvtitle.setText(Title);
    tvcategory.setText(Category);
    tvdescription.setText(Description);
    img.setImageResource(image);
```

Comment: You are trying to pass a `String[]` to a method that only accepts `String`. `tvdescription.setText(Description)`, while `Description` is a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Description as `string []` tp a `tvdescription` text view but text view only support to `string`. That was an issue.

So, first you need to correct that process. For example, you need to identify which data need to show in the text view from the string array that you used.

OR,

If you want to show string array on text view you should set that string array to string. For that, you could try below solutions,

**Solution 1**

```
String[] Description = { "first", "second", "third"}
// Print as [first, second, third ]
tvdescription.setText(Arrays.toString(Description));   

// Print as first, second, third 
tvdescription.setText(Arrays.toString(Description).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

**Solution 2**

```
String[] Description = { "first", "second", "third"}

StringBuilder descriptionText = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: Description) {
    descriptionText.append(s);
    descriptionText.append(" ");
}

tvdescription.setText(descriptionText.toString().trim());
```